# Сессия пользователя

Tags: python, веб-программирование, flask, tornado

Пишу небольшой проект на связке flask + tornado. На flask написан общий функционал (на данный момент авторизация + регистрация пользователей, также создана модель), на торнадо пытаюсь написать чат.

Как tornado научить понимать, под каким пользователем мы сейчас авторизованы, и от его имени писать в чат сообщения?

P.S. Если кто желает поучастовать в разработке данного проекта - милости прошу. Хочу сделать нечто для голосового общения в веб. Цель - получения опыта в подобного рода разработке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень интересный и актуальный вопрос для Tornado. Способов реализации много, торнадо тем и хорош что из коробки нет никакого навязанного решения, можно дать волю фантазии и заточить все максимально вкусно для своего проекта.

Предлагаю такой вариант (опускаю лишний код, чтобы показать только суть):

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    ...

    def get_current_user(self):
        user = None
        user_json = self.get_secure_cookie("mysite_cookie_user")
        if not user_json:
            return None
        logging.info("User ID:%s is get response", str(user_json))
        try:
            user = tornado.escape.json_decode(user_json)
        except Exception:
            logging.info("Error get user cookie")
        return user

    def get_visiter_settings(self):
        settings_json = self.get_secure_cookie("mysite_cookie_settings")
        try:
            cur_settings = tornado.escape.json_decode(settings_json)
            logging.info("Visiter settings:%s is get response from cookie.", str(cur_settings))
        except Exception:
            logging.info("Error get settings from cookie.")
            logging.info("Init new cookie settings.")
            cur_settings = {
                "visitor_uuid": str(uuid.uuid4()),
                "option1": "foo",

                ...

                "option10": "bar"}
            self.set_secure_cookie("mysite_cookie_settings", json.dumps(cur_settings))
            logging.info("New cookie settings initialize.")
        finally:
            return cur_settings

class MainHandler(BaseHandler):

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self,*args, **kwargs):
        current_user = self.get_current_user()
        visiter_settings = self.get_visiter_settings()
```

Хеши сессий можно хранить например в Redis.

В хендлерах состояние сессий можно получать и обновлять по ключам сформированным от current_user и visiter_settings["visitor_uuid"].

Например, для гостей сессии определять по visitor_uuid, для авторизованных по current_user + можно их линковать к их уже существующей сессии по visitor_uuid.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, например, по `cookies`

Если у вас общая база логично передавать логин в `secure_cookies`. На этом принципе основана аутентификация `tornado` [из коробки](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/security.html)

Про фласк не скажу, увы с ним не сталкивался, но думаю там есть что-то похожее или в крайнем случаем можно написать самому.